# [ios.cocos2d+box2d]how to disable auto-rotation?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have created a project with cocos2d 0.99.5 + box2d.
When I rotate my iphone, Screen automatically rotated too.
So the boxes Flew up into the ceiling.

How to disable auto-rotation?

plz

Comment: Alur, did we answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

In coco2d 0.99.5, the template creates a file called GameConfig.h, where you get to choose what system controls the app's rotation. The default is

```
#define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationUIViewController
```

Now take a look inside RootViewController.m, or whatever you've named it in your file. in the

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

method, you'll see a number of `#if` and `#elif` compiler directives. Check out the section that kGameAutorotationUIViewController sends us to:

```
#elif GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
//
// EAGLView will be rotated by the UIViewController
//
// Sample: Autorotate only in landscpe mode
//
// return YES for the supported orientations
if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
   interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight )
    return YES;

// Unsupported orientations:
// UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait, UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown
return NO;
```

To keep your game at a single orientation, change that middle if statement to read:

```
if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    return YES;
```

Or whatever orientation you decide it is that you want. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my application delegate and it stays in landscape no matter which way I turn it:

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application
{
    // CC_DIRECTOR_INIT()
    //
    // 1. Initializes an EAGLView with 0-bit depth format, and RGB565 render buffer
    // 2. EAGLView multiple touches: disabled
    // 3. creates a UIWindow, and assign it to the "window" var (it must already be declared)
    // 4. Parents EAGLView to the newly created window
    // 5. Creates Display Link Director
    // 5a. If it fails, it will use an NSTimer director
    // 6. It will try to run at 60 FPS
    // 7. Display FPS: NO
    // 8. Device orientation: Portrait
    // 9. Connects the director to the EAGLView
    //
    CC_DIRECTOR_INIT();

    // Obtain the shared director in order to...
    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    // Sets landscape mode
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];

    // Turn on display FPS
    [director setDisplayFPS:YES];

    // Turn on multiple touches
    EAGLView *view = [director openGLView];
    [view setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

    // Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
    // It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
    // You can change anytime.
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];    


    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: [HelloWorld scene]];
}
```